# Collapse and Expand table rows that are not nested

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with rows that are not nested although they appear to be. I can't make changes to this layout at all, this is what I have to work with.

The rows with the + collapses the rows below them and the "nested" rows collapsed the rows below them etc. My solution works to some extent. The problem I'm having is that the second to last "nested" row collapses every below it, including the rows it shouldn't. I know why, I can't figure out how to solve it though.

Best way to see what I'm talking about is by playing with the fiddle. You'll see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/pc1sp8L6/

*EDIT*

I have to be able to reuse this function so I have to keep it generic. That is why I'm not using specific classes etc.

HTML

```
<table>
        <tr class="parent-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="parent-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="parent-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="child-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="parent-row has-children">
            <td><span class="toggle">+</span><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-row">
            <td><a href="javascript:;">Heading</a></td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JS

```
(function() {

var toggle = $('span.toggle');

toggle.on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var objectClass = $this.parent().parent().attr('class');

    toggleRow($this, objectClass);

});

function toggleRow(element, elClass) {

    var classes = elClass.split(' ');
    var textList = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
    {
        if (classes[i].length > 0)
        {
            textList += "."+classes[i];
        }
    }
    var $this = element.parents(textList);

    if(!$this.hasClass('collapsed')) {

        $this.addClass('collapsed').nextUntil('tr' + textList).hide();

    } else {

        $this.removeClass('collapsed').nextUntil('tr' + textList).show();

    }
}

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent-row').click(function(){
    var $element = $(this).next();
    while(!$element.hasClass('parent-row')){
        $element.toggle();
        if($element.next().length >0){
            $element = $element.next();   
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
});

$('.child-row.has-children').click(function(){
    var $element = $(this).next();
    while($element.hasClass('child-child-row')){
        $element.toggle();
        if($element.next().length >0){
            $element = $element.next();   
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pc1sp8L6/2/

Or a more generic solution might look like this

```
$('tr[class]').click(function(){
    var thisclass = $(this).attr("class");
    var $element = $(this).next();
    while(!$element.hasClass(thisclass)){
        $element.toggle();
        if($element.next().length >0){
            $element = $element.next();   
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pc1sp8L6/3/

Comment: Thanks @godmode. It solves my problem but presents another problem. Collapse the nested rows and then collapse the parent row. The nested rows pop back in. This is obviously because of the jquery toggle function. I can work with this but ideally I would have liked to handle this effect as generically as possible. I might have to use this function elsewhere on a table with different classes. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: @wind_kind, take a look at my last edit, this is much more generic, but doesn't support children within children

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best/cleanest way of doing this but it does what I need.

```
function toggleRow(element, elClass) {

    var classes = elClass.split(' ');
    var textList = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
    {
        if (classes[i].length > 0)
        {
            textList += "."+classes[i];
        }
    }

    var $this = element.parents(textList);
    var lastRow = $this.index() == $('tr' + textList).last().index() ? true : false;

    if($this.attr('data-collapse') !== 'collapsed') {

        if(!lastRow) {
            $this.attr('data-collapse', 'collapsed').nextUntil('tr' + textList).hide();
        } else {
            $this.attr('data-collapse', 'collapsed').nextUntil('tr.has-children').hide();
        }

    } else {

        if(!lastRow) {
            $this.attr('data-collapse', '').nextUntil('tr' + textList).show();
        } else {
            $this.attr('data-collapse', '').nextUntil('tr.has-children').show();
        }

    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4nvcn00a/