# Collapsing and expanding multiple nested rows in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little help with collapsing and expanding nested rows. Currently my code below expands and collapses as desired at the first level but the subsequent levels also show.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.collapseTitle').click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .parent()
      .next('tbody')
      .toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="collapseTitle">Title</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="collapsed">
    <tr>
      <td>Level 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Level 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to achieve that Level 1 expands when "collapseTitle" is clicked and that only when "collapseAccount" is clicked, does Level 2 expand. Now I know that my code should look something like the below, but I am struggling...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="collapseTitle">Title</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="collapsed account">
      <td class="collapseAccount">Level 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="collapsed level">
      <td>Level 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.collapseTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().next('tbody tr').toggleClass('account');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.collapseAccount').click(function() {
        $(this).next('tr').toggleClass('level');
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your rows are not nested, they are siblings.

Comment: $('.collapseAccount').click(function() {
        $(this).next('tr').toggleClass('level');  --> change it to $(this).parent().next().toggleClass('level');
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do it. I hope it helps with what you want to achieve:

1. collapses/expands columns when clicking on the header/title of the column and
2. collapses/expands all rows following the `account` row when clicking on it (until the next `account` row)

The only thing you need to do is add the class `account` to the higher level rows. You can do this pretty easily when you're displaying these with a loop.

```css
.collapsed {
  /* using visibility, since display causes layout issues */
  /* due to empty rows rows/columns collapsing */
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Title1</td>
      <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="account">
      <td class="collapsed">Account Summary - Account A</td>
      <td class="collapsed">Account Summary - Account A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part I - Account A</td>
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part I - Account A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part II - Account A</td>
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part II - Account A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="account">
      <td class="collapsed">Account Summary - Account B</td>
      <td class="collapsed">Account Summary - Account B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part I - Account B</td>
      <td class="collapsed">Account Details Part I - Account B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
  
    /* the following handlers expand/collapse the columns */
    $('thead > tr > td').each((i, el) => {
      $(el).click(() => {
        const colIndex = $(el).index() + 1;
        const nRows = $('tbody > tr').length;
        for (let j = 0; j < nRows; j += 1) {
          let cellSelector = `tbody > tr:nth-child(${j+1})`
          cellSelector += `> td:nth-child(${colIndex})`;
          $(cellSelector).toggleClass('collapsed');
        }
      })
    })

    /* the following handlers expand/collapse the account-details rows */
    $('tbody > tr.account').each((i, el) => {
      $(el).click(() => {
        $(el).nextUntil('.account').each((j, ele) => {
          $(ele).toggleClass('collapsed');
        })
      })
    })
  });
  
  
</script>
```

Comment: if I had multiple "account-details" per account. How would I adjust your code to account for that ?

Comment: Instead of using jQuery's .next(), you can use .nextUntil() which returns an Array, which you can then loop over. This also simplifies the usage of classes further: use `.nextUntil('.account')`. You can then omit the `account-details` class entirely since it just looks for the next row with the `account` class. I adjusted the answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much ! that works like a charm. The only issue im having now is that because of the collapse class being on the body, the "details" are being displayed when I expand the "account". Is there any way around this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse class being on the body"? What should happen when you expand the account?

Comment: When you click on the "Title", the account is meant to expand. Only when clicking on the account should the details expand. Currently, the account and details expand when the title is clicked on.

Comment: You just need to set the defaults appropriately and hide everything from the get-go. I've made the change to my answer - see above. Btw, if your original question is answered, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selectors are just a bit off for the toggleClass. You can use the class names of the row to toggle. Also you should create a class to be toggled that displays the row/hides it. For example:

edit:

I now created the titles and rows dynamically to give you a better idea of how this can be done using `data-` attributes.

You will have a title td and a row td that match on a `data-` attribute, so when you click a title and corresponding tr will be shown. So for example if you click title 1 (with a `data-index=1`) then the tr with the attribute `data-rowindex=1` will be shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  createTable();
  
  $('.collapseTitle').click(function() {
  
    // grab the data-index value from the clicked title
    let index = $(this).attr("data-index");
    
    // find a tr that has the attribute data-rowindex and it matches index 
    $("tr[data-rowindex='" + index + "']").toggleClass("collapsed");
  });
});

function createTable(){
  // create the titles and the level rows
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  
    // create the title row
    let $trTitle = $('<tr>');
    let $tdTitle = $('<td>', {class: "collapseTitle", text: "Title " + i});
    $tdTitle.attr("data-index", i);
    let $finalTitleRow = $trTitle.append( $tdTitle );
    
    // create the level row
    let $trLevel = $('<tr>', {class: "collapsed account"} );
    $trLevel.attr("data-rowindex", i);
    let $tdLevel = $('<td>', {text: "Level " + i});
    let $finalLevelRow = $trLevel.append( $tdLevel );
    
    // add the title and level row pairs to the head and body
    $("#myTableHead").append($finalTitleRow[0]);
    $("#myTableBody").append($finalLevelRow[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="myTableHead">
  </thead>

  <tbody id="myTableBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Andrew, thank you for your advice. The problem that Im having with your suggestion is that when used with a loop to have multiple titles, they all expand when one is clicked as appose to only the clicked item.

Comment: @5abre I updated my example to hopefully give you a better understanding of how you can do this with dynamically created elements.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to find the answer I was looking for... Thank you to "stackoverfloweth",
[Answer To My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970795/collapse-and-expand-table-rows-that-are-not-nested)

The snippet of code which has helped me thus far is below,

```
$('.parent-row').click(function(){
var $element = $(this).next();
while(!$element.hasClass('parent-row')){
    $element.toggle();
    if($element.next().length >0){
        $element = $element.next();   
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
} });

$('.child-row.has-children').click(function(){
var $element = $(this).next();
while($element.hasClass('child-child-row')){
    $element.toggle();
    if($element.next().length >0){
        $element = $element.next();   
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
} });
```